# Multiple selection list box infopath remove

Tags: infopath

Im new in sharepoint and i have something to do in sharepoint 2010.

Here is the case;

I have two multiple selection list box that is connected to each other.
When i select one of the choices in multiple selection list box1 the corresponding choices appears in multiple selection listbox2 which is perfectly ok
What i want to achieve is that when i unselect the choices in multiple selection listbox1 the corresponding choices in multiple selection listbox2 must be clear or remove.

I try to manipulate it in the Add Rule section but it is not succesful.
Do you have any other way you can show me? Or any code ?

Thak you in advance and i would greatly appreciate your help.